# WooCommerce Variable Product Price not showing on single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I made custom `attribute` for `variation` other than size or colour, but when i apply as `variation` to this `attribute` its not showing on single page.

Comment: What was the name of your custom attribute?

Comment: Look at line 9 of your custom attribute, the error is there

Comment: Attribute name: Custom Box

Comment: Ok did you fill all required fields properly for each variation? Such as price.

Comment: Yes prices are same but i fill each variation correctly.(I think)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's seems you have all variations same price. That's why it's not showing, it's a WooCommerce default behavior. You can change this WooCommerce default variable price filter with this hook.

```
   add_filter('woocommerce_show_variation_price',      function() { return TRUE;});
```

Comment: Add this code on your functions.php file

Comment: +1, nice find. I might just use WordPress's built in function to simplify it a bit: `add filter( 'woocommerce_show_variation_price', '__return_true' );`.

Comment: Thank You it's working fine now

Comment: It worked for me as well!